# Как преобразовать картинку .png в sprite(2D and UI) программно?

Tags: c#, unity3d, изображения, спрайт

Как программно преобразовать картинку в sprite программно?
Я получаю список картинок так:

```
public void GetFileSetObj() {
     DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Application.dataPath+"/TerrainTools/Icon");
     myList = new List<mapObject>();
     foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles()) {
        //получаем расширение файла и проверяем подходит ли оно нам 
        if (Path.GetExtension(file.FullName) == ".png") {
            // Debug.Log("file://"+file.FullName.Replace("\\","/"));
            using (WWW www = new WWW("file:///"+file.FullName.Replace("\\","/"))) {
            // using (WWW www = new WWW("file:///D:/Unity/terranetools.git/Assets/TerrainTools/Icon/100t03g.rsc_V0079757130.png")) {
                if (www.error == null) {
                    Debug.Log("WWW Ok!: " + www.url);
                    mapObject tempmO = new mapObject();
                    tempmO.icon = www.texture;
                    myList.Add(tempmO);
                } else {
                    Debug.Log("WWW Error: "+ www.error);
                }
            }
        }   
     }
}
```

Как теперь автоматически преобразовать картинки в sprite(2D and UI)?

Answer (score 0):

Так как изображения изначально получаем как текстура то к примеру можно создать спрайт и назначить на него вашу текстуру:

```
Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.one / 2);
```

Comment: у меня есть ссылка на картинку. Как текстуру определить по ссылке?